# Secure connection between my API REST and my website/script

Tags: java, bash, api, rest

I know the question may have already been asked but i can't find an answer...

I'am developping a website and i know that in the future it will be an app version of it. So i've decided to do one Api that will be called by my website and my app.

**First question** : Is it a good idea to do it that way ?

I'm asking myself now how can i secure the connection between my api rest and my website, i don't want anyone else than my website to call method on my api. I was thinking about OAuth1 but from what i have read Oauth1 is more for connecting two strangers website together when in my case they are both mine.

**Second question** : How to secure the connection between my API REST and my website ?

In another project (nothing to do with the first one) i need to do the same thing but between an API REST and a bash script. Same thing they both are mine.

**Third question** : How to secure the connection between my API REST and my bash script ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Create your own root certificate and install at your REST server and REST client, then use https to secure your REST connection. As for securing connection between website and public users, you need buy a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: @waltersu But not from Comodo as I read today ...

Comment: What is your *website*? A javascript front end, or a full java server site *redirecting* requests to a *hidden* site?

Comment: Create my own root certificate ? Sorry but i'm new to all those security issues..

Comment: I've just finished creating the REST API so i don't know it yet, but i think it will be a java or php server which will like you said kinda "redirect requests" to my API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup *security* at different levels, targeting different things. If you have full control on a web server that will be be only client of a REST API server, the most secure operation you can do if both share same infrastructure is to forbid any external requests on the API server and only allow requests from the web server.

This can be done with a reverse proxy in front of the API server that knows the IP address(es) of the web server and only allow requests from there, if both are in the same *zone* say on a lan behind the same firewall to physically forbid an attacker to use the web server IP. If both servers have to connect through the wild internet, you should setup a VPN between them to achieve the same security level.

But this will no longer be useable as soon as you will have an app that would connect to the API server, because now requests can come from anywhere. As such I strongly advice not to let the API server security rely on the app: whatever you try, an attacker can disassemble the code of the app, run it on a debugger and spy the network to understand how it exchange with the API server. Now, the common usage is to *authenticate* a user (password for simple, *low level* security, certificate delivered by a company that you trust - eventually yours - for high level security). And you must now secure the API server to only allow certain methods to certain users - eventually on certain domain objects. Spring Security is a tool of choice for this. Of course sensitive informations - which includes all authentication related information - shall only use HTTPS.

The rule here is that security shall not depend of something that can be faked or easily stolen among which you find:

- a public (external) IP address
- a protocol between an app and a server
- a password shared between different users or machines
- information transmitted in clear over uncrypted HTTP.

[Information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is *the* site to ask experts on security when you will have more precise questions.

For you third question, it does not matter whether requests are asked via a browser, an app or a bash script. What matters is only how you can identify the user who is behind the request.

Comment: Waouh ! Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, it helps me a lot. I think on the case of my Script/APIconnection i'll do it with a simple password stored in a file only readable by the certain users. For my API/Website/App i'll do it with OAuth i think.